# How to send integer with pipe between two processes!

Tags: c, linux, ipc, pipe

I am trying to send an integer with pipe in a POSIX system but `write()` function is working for sending string or character data. Is there any way to send integer with a pipe?

Regards

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The safe way is to use `snprintf` and `strtol`.

But if you know both processes were created using the same version of compiler (for example, they're the same executable which `fork`ed), you can take advantage of the fact that anything in C can be read or written as an array of `char`:

```
int n = something();
write(pipe_w, &n, sizeof(n));

int n;
read(pipe_r, &n, sizeof(n));
```

Comment: Every pointer can be casted to a *char. But I'm not sure if the opposite is correct without violating the strict aliasing rules?

Comment: @cebewee: Not sure exactly what your question is.  `(short*)(char*) &n` will violate strict aliasing when dereferenced.  But `short first_two_bytes; memcpy(&first_two_bytes, &n, sizeof(first_two_bytes));` does not violate strict aliasing.

Comment: @cebewee - It's not char *, it's void *. And every pointer can be a void *. Though you might still be right. This might violate the strict aliasing rules and the value of `n` in the second case might not change.

Comment: Functions like `write` and `read` which deal with the data in a `void*` will typically have to cast the pointer to `char*` or `unsigned char*`.  (Insert "or `const` ..." as appropriate.)  But `char` and `unsigned char` lvalues are forbidden from strict-aliasing optimizations for this reason.

Comment: You are right. I was confusing writing to an int through a char* (which is allowed) with accessing a char through an int* (which violates strict aliasing).

Comment: @aschepler I am a complete beginner, and I have a question. I compiled my code and it says, pipe_w & pipe_r  are not declared, I tried using **pipe pipe_r,pipe_w;** but it didn't work. Kindly lemme know, what I am doing wrong here, Thank You :)

Answer (score 2):

Either send a string containing the ASCII representation of integer e.g., `12345679`, or send four bytes containing the binary representation of int, e.g., `0x00`, `0xbc`, `0x61`, `0x4f`.

In the first case, you will use a function such as `atoi()` to get the integer back.

Answer (score 0):

Aschelpler's answer is right, but if this is something that can grow later I recommend you use some kind of simple protocol library like Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) or just JSON or XML with some basic schema.

Answer (score 0):

Below one works fine for writing to pipe and reading from pipe as:

```
stop_daemon =123;
res = write(cli_pipe_fd_wr, &stop_daemon, sizeof(stop_daemon));
....
res = read(pipe_fd_rd, buffer, sizeof(int));
memcpy(&stop_daemon,buffer,sizeof(int));
printf("CLI process read from res:%d status:%d\n", res, stop_daemon);
```

output:

```
CLI process read from res:4 status:123
```